# Quartz.net used in WebAPI does not trigger in Azure Website hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, cron, quartz.net, azure-web-app-service

**Problem:** 
Quartz.net scheduler triggers fine locally but not when deployed to Azure Website.

**Details:**
My ASP.NET web application allows users to create multiple scheduled jobs. A job is to send an email to user at a given time everyday. User creates a scheduled job from website that calls a WebAPI endpoint. That endpoint implementation in WebAPI uses [Quartz.net](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) to create daily scheduled jobs as follows:

```
[Route("api/jobs/test")]
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Test()
{
  IJobDetail _detail = JobBuilder.Create<MailJob>()
    .WithIdentity("TestMail", "MailGroup")
    .Build();

  _detail.JobDataMap.Add("TestMail", "mail@address.com");
  ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithIdentity("Trigger1", "GenericGroup")
    .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.RepeatForever().WithIntervalInHours(24))
    .StartNow()
    .Build();

  Global.Scheduler.ScheduleJob(_detail, trigger);
}
```

And a job is as follows:

```
public class MailJob : IJob
{
    public SnapmailJob()
    { }

    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        SendMail("Test Mail", "Testing @ " + DateTime.UtcNow.ToString(), context.MergedJobDataMap.Get("TestEmail").ToString());
    }
}
```

Quartz.net scheduler is initialized in Global.asax as follows:

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static ISchedulerFactory SchedulerFactory;
    public static IScheduler Scheduler;

    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SchedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        Scheduler = SchedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
        Scheduler.Start();
    }

    protected void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Scheduler.Shutdown();
    }
}
```

**Note:** 
I saw people using Quartz.net settings in web.config. But i am not using any.

Comment: Does it not work at all? Do you have "Always On" configuration set for your Website (you need it)?

Comment: Thanks Amit, It does not working at all. Even I have enabled "Always On" in Azure Portal for this site.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue?

Comment: No, I opted for a workaround which suited my case. I needed multiple schedulers to run simultaneously and send email on set time everyday after some image processing. Used window service that manages multiple threads, one for single scheduled task.  Each runs infinitely until user sets its scheduled task to Stop.